# asterisk - extensions.conf file

Tags: ubuntu, asterisk

I would like to ask:

can I have in exnetnsions.conf file:

```
[me]

include => internal

[internal]

exten =>...
```

OR

I need to have :

```
[internal]

exten => ...

[me]
include => internal
```

Is there a difference on how I put them?

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with including in any order you wish.

Comment: but can i add in [me] sip users? or i need to add all the sip users extensions in [internal]? why?

Comment: I think you should consider reading more about *contexts* in asterisk.
here is one resource i found: http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+config+extensions.conf

Comment: I did. now you are asking me another question which im not sure how to answer. please open another question if you want it answered.

Comment: i've resoled the problem. thx very much.I have a new question about trying to reload asterisk from command line in c file. the thing is that is not working.

Comment: my question is can i call system() method from web service?

Comment: I don't seem to know how stackoverflow works. this is not a 1 on 1 session, please read the FAQ